# How to integrate CloudFormation with CodeDeploy and AutoScaling groups

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-code-deploy

Our CloudFormation template creates an autoscaling group with a random name. Right now we need to go to the CodeDeploy console and manually add the new autoscaling group to the deployment group - we would like to automate this process. For example, it would be nice if we could create a staging environment using the CloudFormation template and deploy code to it without any manual steps.

I can see two ways to do it:

1. Get CloudFormation to always assign the autoscaling group the same name, and just configure it ones in the CodeDeploy console
2. Have CloudFormation modify CodeDeploy with the new autoscaling group name.

It seems like CloudFormation doesn't allow either approach - any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I would do:

- Put the name of the autoscaling group in the Outputs section of your template.
- After creating the stack, call describe-stack to retrieve the autoscaling group name from Outputs.
- Use the CodeDeploy API to add the autoscaling group to the deployment group.

If you put this in a simple script, you can easily create as many ad-hoc stacks/staging environments as you please. (And you probably want a similar script for removing the stack.)

Comment: thanks! was thinking along the same lines. It's not particularly hard, but I was hoping that there is a native aws solution for that.

Comment: part of the problem is that when using ELB HealthCheck in the autoscaling group, you want to set HealthCheckGracePeriod to something fairly small. Having to execute the above step manually forces you to set the value to something really high.

Comment: Why is that? Wouldn't the time it takes to make the CodeDeploy API call be relatively small compared to the time of starting the instances themselves?

Comment: You would think that but Codedeploy typically takes 3-5 minutes for the DownLoadBundle to complete (even for a tiny code base) and often 2 minutes for the InstallApp to complete. Seven minutes is actually longer than it takes for the AMI to boot up.